# real analytic function taking infintiely many zeros in an interval is the zero function?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Suppose we have a real analytic function $f$ defined on a closed interval $[a,b]$, where $a < b$. Suppose there are infinitely many zeros of $f$ in the interval. Does it then imply that $f \equiv 0$? I know that analogous statement holds for complex analytic function, but I was not sure about the real case. Any comments would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.  A real analytic function on $[a,b]$ is the restriction to $[a,b]$ of a complex analytic function on some open set containing $[a,b]$.  So the result for complex analytic functions gives you what you need.